# Can't insert space character when using neovim with parinfer

Tags: visual-studio-code, neovim

I'm experiencing a problem where if my cursor is to the left of a `)` then when I hit space it just moves the cursor to the other side of the `)` character instead of inserting a new space character as expected.

This only happens when I use the neovim plugin and have parinfer installed on neovim.
This only happens when using vscode, and not when just using neovim.